# Using datasets in an R package

Tags: r, cran

I am trying to get the latest version of my package (https://github.com/jmcurran/relSim) on CRAN. This has been rejected because of the use of a data set that is included in the package in a function which is not exported (i.e. the user cannot use it unless they use the `:::` operator. A code snippet:

```
testIS = function(nc = c(3, 2), locus = 1, seed = 123456){
  set.seed(seed)
  np = 2 * nc[2]
  freqs = USCaucs$freqs
```

The dataset is included in the package, and as per Hadley's advice I have `LazyData: true` in my DESCRIPTION file. However I get this note from https://win-builder.r-project.org which I don't know how to resolve.

```
 * checking R code for possible problems ... [11s] NOTE
 testIS: no visible binding for global variable 'USCaucs'
 Undefined global functions or variables::
   USCaucs
```

I find this especially frustrating, since, as I said, this function is not even exported (it also works without complaint because the package loads this dataset). All help appreciated

Comment: Was the package rejected because of the note? Were you given any further details? For internal data, the recommendation is to use `R/sysdata.rda`.

Comment: Yes @aocall - there is now a CRAN pre-check system which seems to be based of winbuilder. The resolution - which you've prompted me to post as an answer to my own question is/was as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The solution appears to involve a little duplication. At the suggestion of Thomas Lumley, I placed the object in `R/sysdata.rda` as well as having it in `data/USCaucs.rda`. I followed Hadley Wickham's suggestion to use `devtools::use_data` with the argument `internal` set to `TRUE` so that it was saved in the correct manner for a package.

As noted, this solution involves duplicating the data. This isn't an issue for a small object such as the one I have here, but I'd like to think there is a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: You could (hard? sym?) link one file to the other, and script this step in `data-raw/USCaucs.rda`

Comment: I have the same situation, the data is used inside functions but is also a useful reference for the user to have access to. I guess I will duplicate it as you have done

Comment: I had exactly the same situation as you @see24 but I couldn't bear the inelegance of having the same dataset as both internal and exported (not sure why!) The solution that worked for me was to use the package namespace when I needed to reference the exported data (to treat it as internal, effectively?) - see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410084/5168907. This feels weird because obviously within a package you don't normally need to namespace reference your own functions - but you do need to for data (if not internal) - I think. Another approach would be to call `data(mydataset)`.